# Крашится приложение при использовании Pimary Key, переданного через intent

Tags: android, android-room, room

В MainActivity создаю объект для добавление в БД Room.

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_lists")
public class MainList {

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

private String name;

public MainList(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Далее я его добавляю при помощи viewModel в базу данных, дальше с этого объекта я получаю id, name - передаю через интент в другое активити.

```
MainList mainList = new MainList("Новый список");
        viewModel.insertMainList(mainList);
```

Все через AsyncTask естесно, запуск активити происходит через StarActivityForResult, в новой активити я пробую через Toast вытащить idшник и приложение вылетает.

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();

    setTitle("Edit goods");
    list_name = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
    list_id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
    editText_listName.setText(list_name);
    Toast.makeText(this, list_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в LogCat есть вывод сообщения об ошибке. Если бы вы туда посмотрели, то увидели бы, что не найден строковый ресурс в методе `Toast.makeText(Context context, @StringRes int stringId, int length)`.

Это происходит потому, что вы не тот метод вызываете. Вам надо вызывать метод  `Toast.makeText(Context context, String string, int length)`, передавая туда строку (переменную `list_name` ), а не число. Или прeобразовав число в строку `String.valueOf(list_id)`

Comment: Юрий, спасибо за ответ. Я тестировал ещё и с установкой этого id как текста в editText. Точно также все вылетает. А при конкатенации в другой editText со стринговым значение все проходит отлично.

Comment: В TextView и его наследниках также есть метод, принимающий число-ID строкового ресурса. Потому и вылетает с той же ошибкой. Если вам ответ помог - можете его отметить "верным", нажав галочку слева от тела ответа)